# Truncation of a file stored a Varbinary(max)

Tags: php, linux, apache, sql-server-2008, pdo

I am trying to upload a file in SQL server 2008 database using PHP 5.4. The code to download the same file works fine except for the files having size more than 64KB. When I download a file more than 64 KB, it is getting truncated to 64KB.

When I try same thing locally, it works perfectly but gives file truncation issue only on the development server. The website is hosted in linux environment.

I am converting the file content using bin2hex() function as follows.

```
$fileContent=file_get_contents($_FILES[$key]["tmp_name"]);                
$fileContent="0x".bin2hex($fileContent);
```

Then while downloading I am using following code.

```
  private $fileContents = '';
  private $fileName = '';
  private $contentType = '';

  public function __construct()
  {
    //parent::__construct();
    if (Tools::getPostVar('documentID')!="")
    {
      ini_set ('mssql.textlimit', 2147483647);
      ini_set ('mssql.textsize', 2147483647);
      $this->getFile();
      $this->showFile();
    }
    else
      Tools::ThrowError('Document ID not set', 'Document ID not set');
  }

  private function getFile()
  {
     $cn  = new DbMobTool();
     $cn->bIsConnPersist = false;
     $cn->doQuery("exec stp_my_procedure ".Tools::getPostVar("documentID"));
     $rs = $cn->fetchAll();

     switch (Tools::getEnvironment()) {
         case 'local':
            $this->fileContents = hex2bin($rs[0]->document);
            break;
         case 'dev':
         case 'stage':
         case 'prod':
           $this->fileContents = $rs[0]->document;
           break;
       }

    $this->fileName = $rs[0]->document_name;

        $s = strrchr($this->fileName, ".");
        $s = substr($s, 1, 3);
        switch (strtolower($s))
        {
            case 'pdf':
                $this->contentType = 'application/pdf';
                break;
            case 'jpg':
                $this->contentType = 'image/pjpeg';
                break;
            case 'xls':
                $this->contentType = 'application/vnd.ms-excel';
                break;
            case 'ppt':
                $this->contentType = 'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint';
                break;
            default:
                $this->contentType = 'text/plain';
        }

    $cn->closeDbObject($rs);    
  }

  private function showFile()
  {
    ob_clean();
    ob_start();
    //header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    //header('Expires: 0');
    //header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    if ($this->contentType != '')
    {
      header ('Content-Type: ' . $this->contentType);
      header ('Content-Title: ' . $this->contentType);
    }
    if(strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'MSIE')===false)
      header ('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $this->fileName . '"');
    else
      header ('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . str_replace('+',' ',urlencode($this->fileName)) . '"');

    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    //clean all levels of output buffering
    while (ob_get_level()) {
        ob_end_clean();
    }
    echo $this->fileContents;
    //ob_end_flush();  // Stops output buffering and 'flushes' output to client browser
  }
```

I have spent lot of time fixing this. Not sure whether it is a configuration issue or something I missed during posting the file.

Thanks in advance.